# Check if hot key pressed in Winforms

Tags: winforms, hotkeys

To catch the hot key `Ctrl+A`, we can use following statement in `Form1_KeyDown`.

```
if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Test");
}
```

To catch `Ctrl+Alt+A`, we can use:

```
if (e.Control && e.Alt)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
    {
        // Your code goes here
    }
}
```

The question is how to catch the hot key like `Ctrl+A+B`?

Comment: You mean `Ctrl+A, CTRL+B` (`CTRL+A` followed by `B` while the `CTRL` Key is still pressed - or, the `CTRL` Key has not been released).

Comment: @Jimi still pressed

Comment: There is no easy way to do this in WinForms. you'd have to keep a dictionary of bools and keep track of what keys were pressed. Or, you can import WPF runtimes and use `Keyboard.IsKeyDown` in combination with the `KeyDown` event. You could also resort to the Win32 API and using thing like `GetKeyState`

Comment: Should this "hotkey" only work within YOUR application?

Answer (score 1):

Here's something to get you started using [IMessageFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter?view=net-5.0).

This will trigger when Ctrl-A-B is pressed DOWN, not on release.  It also currently will repeatedly trigger while those keys are held down.  This could be changed with another boolean variable in the mix.  This is definitely not perfect...

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{   

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private MyFilter mf = new MyFilter();

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mf.Ctrl_A_B += Mf_Ctrl_A_B;
        Application.AddMessageFilter(mf);
    }

    private void Mf_Ctrl_A_B()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ctrl-A-B was held down!");
    }

}

public class MyFilter : IMessageFilter
{

    private bool keyCtrl;
    private bool keyA;
    private bool keyB;

    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
    private const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;

    public delegate void dlg_Ctrl_A_B();
    public event dlg_Ctrl_A_B Ctrl_A_B;

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        Keys keyData;
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_KEYDOWN:
                keyData = (Keys)((int)m.WParam);
                switch (keyData)
                {
                    case Keys.ControlKey:
                        keyCtrl = true;
                        break;

                    case Keys.A:
                        keyA = true;
                        break;

                    case Keys.B:
                        keyB = true;
                        break;
                }
                if (keyCtrl && keyA && keyB)
                {
                    Ctrl_A_B?.Invoke();
                }
                break;

            case WM_KEYUP:
                keyData = (Keys)((int)m.WParam);
                switch (keyData)
                {
                    case Keys.ControlKey:
                        keyCtrl = false;
                        break;

                    case Keys.A:
                        keyA = false;
                        break;

                    case Keys.B:
                        keyB = false;
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: What about `Ctrl+J+E` or any other combination? Should we declare a variable for each?

Comment: It's either that, or create some kind of `Dictionary<Keys, bool>` so you can lookup and toggle specific values.  It's going to get messy either way...

Comment: hmm I don't think so If you allow me. Just a single variable is enough. Something like the other answer. Works for any `Ctrl+Any+Any`. Try it regardless of the vote thing. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @dr.null  The `Dictionary` approach will be the most flexible.  Even your approach will need modification if tomorrow they ask for Ctrl-A-B-C.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the first key as an additional or a custom modifier to expand the range of the shortcuts.

Declare a class variable to hold that modifier:

```cs
private Keys KeyModifier = Keys.None;
```

Handle the `KeyDown` event as follows:

```cs
private void FormWhatEver_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.B:
                if (KeyModifier == Keys.A)
                {
                    // Handle Ctrl+AB
                }
                else
                {
                    // Handle Ctrl+B
                }
                break;
            case Keys.C:
                if (KeyModifier == Keys.A)
                {
                    // Handle Ctrl+AC
                }
                else
                {
                    // Handle Ctrl+C
                }
                break;
            default:
                // Otherwise set the pressed key as a key modifier.
                KeyModifier = e.KeyCode;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Reset the modifier when the `Control` key is released. This is important in order to make the above work correctly.

```cs
private void FormWhatEver_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.Control) KeyModifier = Keys.None;
}
```