# Detecting KeyDown when pressing a button

Tags: c#, binding, keypress

I'm working on an AutoClicker and I want to be able turn the clicker on or off with a hotkey. I also want the hotkey to be bindable so for starters, it'd be nice to click the button and detect what was pressed on the keyboard but whatever I try it just doesn't want to work. I've set `KeyPreview` to true, I've tried what feels like a million ways to do this already.

```
private void autoClickerHKey_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            this.autoClickerHKey.Text = "CLICKER BIND: " + Keys.KeyCode.ToString();
            // HKey = Keys.KeyCode.ToString();
        }
```

Tell me if I'm doing this wrong, but in my head, I can just set `HKey` to `Keys.KeyCode.ToString()` and then use `HKey` in `if(keyData == Keys.HKey)` to toggle my switch on or off.

I'm probably missing something very obvious here, but I've tinkered on this for so long I honestly can't think anymore.

Comment: Not quite clear. If you change the type of the `HKey` variable from **string** to **Keys** `(private Keys HKey = Keys.YourHotKeu;)` then you can compare it with the currently pressed key through the `e.KeyCode` property. Maybe the two answers posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64814678/14171304) give you some hints.

Answer (score 0):

using `e.KeyCode.ToString()` worked over `Keys.KeyCode.ToString()`. I think there was something wrong with my project because I'm pretty sure I tried that method before. Anyways, after just redoing everything as a new project, it works. The issue might've also been me using a bunifu button instead of the default windows button.